# Status Message After Password Reset

Tags: laravel, status, alerts

All this code works just fine except when the password is updated.  I am not getting the status message that password is updated once Auth::logout() is fired and returned to the login screen.  It does change the password but no message.  If there is an error, it returns back and displays a sweetalert message that passwords do not match.

Controller

```
 public function UserUpdatePassword(Request $request)
    {
        $validateData = $request->validate([
            'oldpassword' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed',
        ]);

        $hashedPassword = Auth::user()->password;
        if(Hash::check($request->oldpassword,$hashedPassword)){
           $user = User::find(Auth::id());
           $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
           $user->save();

           Auth::logout(); 
           return redirect()->route('user.logout')->with('status','Password Updated Successfully');   


        } else{
            Alert::warning('Password Mismatch','Current Password Error or Password Confirm Do Not Match');
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
```

on login screen

```
@if (session('status'))
                    <div class="alert" role="alert" style="background-color:#C5ECEB;">
                        {{ session('status') }}
                    </div>
                @endif
```

Comment: How about redirect directly to the `login` route after `Auth::logout()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
Auth::logout();
```

is before showing the status;
So If you want to show the status message, just comment logout line as follows:

```
$user = User::find(Auth::id());
$user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
$user->save();
return redirect()->route('user.logout')->with('status','Password Updated Successfully');
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `\Session::put('status','Password Updated Successfully');`
before `Auth::logout();`